# Android Service Basics

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask, intentservice

I am new to Android services so I had some questions that would clarify how I could use them in my current project.

1) Do I need to have my application running to have the service running? Do I have to launch the application for the services to start?

2) I want to print a text on the screen at the end of my service run. First, is it possible and second, will I be able to see this text on the Activity UI when I switch to the Activity's screen?

3) I want my service to use variables and functions that are implemented in the main Activity class. Is it possible?

4) Related to question 3: I have an AsyncTask in my current application that repeats every minute using a TimerTask. I want to have the same functionality, but this time running in the background when user is busy doing something else. Is Service the right thing to do that? Can I accomplish that by running my searchRegularly() (which is in the Activity) function from the Service? Below, `backgroundSearch` is the name of the AsyncTask that runs every minute.

```
    public void searchRegularly() {

    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    searchTimer = new Timer();
    doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 

                      backgroundSearch = new SearchTask();
                      backgroundSearch.execute();
                }
            });

        }

    };

    searchTimer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 1000,60000);

}
```

5) How do you decide to use whether a Service or an IntentService? What is the main difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No. But the application (I mean the Application class in Manifest, not activity) will be created before your service

2) Do you mean "[toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)"? Yes

3) Though it's possible with some tricks, this is not recommended. Rethink your design.

4) Service can do, or you can consider [AlaramManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

5) Service itself should be a Singleton, no two service of the same class will be running at the same time; for Service, if you call multiple StartService, and if Service is already running, it will not Start twice. But IntentService will work on multiple "start" simultaneously.